# What happens to the additional CSS code in customize section when theme is updated?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a premium theme installed and I need to add some custom CSS to add some new styles.

So what will happen if I add the CSS to the additional css section in the customize? Will I lose them when the theme is updated?

Should I install a plugin or create a simple one for this?

I tried to search about that, But didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The css placed in the customize wont be lost after a theme update.

But the best practice is to [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) in order to customize your theme.